# How to add custom buttons on UI using prompt?

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets, button, prompt

I have this problem. I was trying to build a spreasheet that, on open, would prompt a UI that allows the user to select between 3 custom buttons. A real scenerio would be this:

on open, it displays the message: "Hi! Which project do you wanna work on?" and, below this message, three buttons that say "Project 1", "Project 2" and "Project 3". Depending on the button pressed, It should modify the spreadsheet accordingly (for example, It would unify A1:A10 and write in it "Project 1" and so on).

How do I do this? Is this possible? Thanks:)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it to the Google Spreadsheet Ui because the button selections are fixed, OK, Cancel and such.  But you can create a custom dialog.

In Code.gs I create an [Installed onOpen](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

```
function myOnOpen(e) {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("HTML_Simple");
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(html,"Test");
}
```

Next I make a simple custom dialog with project buttons called HTML_Simple.html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Which project do you want to work on?</p>
    <input id="project1" type="button" value="Project 1" onclick="clickProject(this)">
    <input id="project2" type="button" value="Project 2" onclick="clickProject(this)">
    <input id="project3" type="button" value="Project 3" onclick="clickProject(this)">
    <script>
      function clickProject(button) {
        try {
          alert("You picked "+button.id);
          google.script.host.close();
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Now you can test the button id and branch to do whatever you want.

Reference

- [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)

Comment: Thank you TheWizEd! So I guess it's impossible to create a prompt on open with a drop down menù, right?

Comment: Not using SpreadsheetApp. Ui.  But the custom dialog I've shown can just as easily be a drop down selection.